# Ajax request dataype JSONP "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm trying to make a very simple ajax request to a json api. I'm using `dataType: 'jsonp'` because it's cross domain and I can't wrap my head around CORS right now.

The request goes through status 200 and I can read all of the users in the network tab in chrome dev tools, but I'm still getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Here's my code:

```
    var url = 'https://api.lookfwd.io/v1/test/users';

    export const fetchUsers = function() {
      return $.ajax({
       dataType: "jsonp",
       url: url,
      });
    }
```

Any ideas on what I should I do?

Comment: Can you post the response you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace with this :-

> dataType: "json",

remove jsonp with json only